# Bulk uploading backlog of xml files to MVC Controller

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc-4, parsing, upload, httprequest

I have an MVC4 application that parses XML files specific to a particular data format, I have this working as expected when uploading the xml file through a file input control and it takes between 1-5 seconds to parse each file.

If however I choose to upload a series of 50 files it seems to take 30-60 seconds per record. What would be the cause of this delay when bulk uploading the 50 files?

I have a backlog of 2000 files to upload and obviously would like to automate this process somehow, any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

```
<HttpPost()> _
<ValidateAntiForgeryToken()> _
Function Create(ByVal file As HttpPostedFileBase) As ActionResult
    If ModelState.IsValid Then

        'Grab the uploaded file from the HttpRequest and save it to the MarketMessageFiles folder
        Dim xmlFile As HttpPostedFileBase

        Dim fileCount = Request.Files.Count

        For fileIteration = 0 To fileCount - 1

            xmlFile = Request.Files(fileIteration)

            Try
                xmlFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/MarketMessageFiles/" + xmlFile.FileName))
            Catch ex As Exception
                Return View()
            End Try



            'Declare Variables for XML Parsing
            'Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument()
            'Dim xmlNodeList As XmlNodeList
            Dim i As Integer
            Dim j As Integer

            'Declare Variables for Entity Creation Values
            Dim TxRefNbr = ""
            Dim RecipientID = ""
            Dim SenderID = ""
            Dim MarketTimestamp = ""
            Dim VersionNumber = ""
            Dim MessageTypeCode = ""
            Dim MPRN = ""

            'Declare Variable for the MarketMessage class
            Dim marketMessage = New MarketMessage

            'Create a FileStream from the file saved in the MarketMessagesFiles folder
            Dim fs As New FileStream(Server.MapPath("~/MarketMessageFiles/" + xmlFile.FileName), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
            xmlDoc.Load(fs)
            xmlNodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("ieXMLDocument")

            'Process the Header Message
            For i = 0 To xmlNodeList.Count - 1

                For j = 0 To xmlNodeList(i).ChildNodes(0).Attributes.Count - 1

                    'Set the relevant variable according to the header attributes
                    Select Case xmlNodeList(i).ChildNodes(0).Attributes(j).Name

                        Case "TxRefNbr" : TxRefNbr = xmlNodeList(i).ChildNodes(0).Attributes(j).Value
                        Case "RecipientID" : RecipientID = xmlNodeList(i).ChildNodes(0).Attributes(j).Value
                        Case "SenderID" : SenderID = xmlNodeList(i).ChildNodes(0).Attributes(j).Value
                        Case "MarketTimestamp" : MarketTimestamp = xmlNodeList(i).ChildNodes(0).Attributes(j).Value
                        Case "VersionNumber" : VersionNumber = xmlNodeList(i).ChildNodes(0).Attributes(j).Value
                        Case "MessageTypeCode" : MessageTypeCode = xmlNodeList(i).ChildNodes(0).Attributes(j).Value
                            'Case "MPRN" : MPRN = xmlNodeList(i).ChildNodes(0).Attributes(j).Value

                    End Select

                Next

            Next

            'Set the MessageHeader attributes
            marketMessage.createdOn = Date.Today
            marketMessage.marketTimeStamp = DateTime.Parse(MarketTimestamp)
            marketMessage.recipient = RecipientID
            marketMessage.sender = SenderID
            'If (Not MPRN = "") Then
            '    marketMessage.mprn = CType(MPRN, Long)
            'End If
            marketMessage.messageType = MessageTypeCode
            marketMessage.txRefNbr = TxRefNbr

            'Add MarketMessage class to database context
            db.MarketMessages.Add(marketMessage)
            Try
                db.SaveChanges()
            Catch ex As DbEntityValidationException
                For Each validationErrors In ex.EntityValidationErrors

                    For Each validationError In validationErrors.ValidationErrors
                        Dim test = validationError.ErrorMessage
                    Next
                Next

            End Try



            'Search the repository using the code and return the market message type
            Dim mmt As MarketMessageType = db.MarketMessageTypes.[Single](Function(_mmt) _mmt.Header = MessageTypeCode)

            'Check the MarketMessageTypeID and process according to the relevant message type
            Select Case mmt.MarketMessageTypeID

                Case 1 : Process010(xmlNodeList)
                Case 2 : Process011(xmlNodeList)
                Case 3 : Process011A(xmlNodeList)
                Case 4 : Process012(xmlNodeList)
                Case 5 : Process012W(xmlNodeList)
                Case 6 : Process013(xmlNodeList)
                Case 7 : Process014R(xmlNodeList)
                Case 8 : Process015(xmlNodeList)
                Case 9 : Process016(xmlNodeList)
                Case 10 : Process017(xmlNodeList)
                Case 11 : Process021(xmlNodeList)
                Case 12 : Process030(xmlNodeList)
                Case 13 : Process101(xmlNodeList)
                Case 14 : Process101P(xmlNodeList)
                Case 15 : Process101R(xmlNodeList)
                Case 16 : Process102(xmlDoc, marketMessage.MarketMessageID)
                Case 17 : Process102P(xmlNodeList)
                Case 18 : Process102R(xmlNodeList)
                Case 19 : Process105(xmlNodeList)
                Case 20 : Process105L(xmlNodeList)
                Case 21 : Process106D(xmlNodeList)
                Case 22 : Process106E(xmlNodeList)
                Case 23 : Process110(xmlNodeList)
                Case 24 : Process111(xmlNodeList)
                Case 25 : Process111A(xmlNodeList)
                Case 26 : Process111L(xmlNodeList)
                Case 27 : Process111R(xmlNodeList)
                Case 28 : Process112(xmlNodeList)
                Case 29 : Process112R(xmlNodeList)
                Case 30 : Process112W(xmlNodeList)
                Case 31 : Process114(xmlNodeList)
                Case 32 : Process115(xmlNodeList)
                Case 33 : Process115R(xmlNodeList)
                Case 34 : Process116(xmlNodeList)
                Case 35 : Process116A(xmlNodeList)
                Case 36 : Process116N(xmlNodeList)
                Case 37 : Process116R(xmlNodeList)
                Case 38 : Process117D(xmlNodeList)
                Case 39 : Process117R(xmlNodeList)
                Case 40 : Process122(xmlNodeList)
                Case 41 : Process122R(xmlNodeList)
                Case 42 : Process130D(xmlNodeList)
                Case 43 : Process130R(xmlNodeList)
                Case 44 : Process131(xmlNodeList)
                Case 45 : Process137R(xmlNodeList)
                Case 46 : Process140(xmlNodeList)
                Case 47 : Process208(xmlNodeList)
                Case 48 : Process210(xmlNodeList)
                Case 49 : Process252(xmlNodeList)
                Case 50 : Process260(xmlNodeList)
                Case 51 : Process261(xmlNodeList)
                Case 52 : Process300(xmlDoc, marketMessage.MarketMessageID)
                Case 53 : Process300S(xmlDoc, marketMessage.MarketMessageID)
                Case 54 : Process300W(xmlDoc, marketMessage.MarketMessageID)
                Case 55 : Process301(xmlNodeList)
                Case 56 : Process301N(xmlNodeList)
                Case 57 : Process303R(xmlNodeList)
                Case 58 : Process305(xmlDoc, marketMessage.MarketMessageID)
                Case 59 : Process306(xmlDoc, marketMessage.MarketMessageID)
                Case 60 : Process306W(xmlNodeList)
                Case 61 : Process307(xmlNodeList)
                Case 62 : Process307W(xmlNodeList)
                Case 63 : Process308(xmlNodeList)
                Case 64 : Process310(xmlDoc, marketMessage.MarketMessageID)
                Case 65 : Process310W(xmlNodeList)
                Case 66 : Process311(xmlNodeList)
                Case 67 : Process320(xmlDoc, marketMessage.MarketMessageID)
                Case 68 : Process320W(xmlDoc, marketMessage.MarketMessageID)
                Case 69 : Process321(xmlNodeList)
                Case 70 : Process330(xmlNodeList)
                Case 71 : Process331(xmlNodeList)
                Case 72 : Process332(xmlDoc, marketMessage.MarketMessageID)
                Case 73 : Process332W(xmlNodeList)
                Case 74 : Process341(xmlDoc, marketMessage.MarketMessageID)
                Case 75 : Process342(xmlDoc, marketMessage.MarketMessageID)
                Case 76 : Process352R(xmlNodeList)
                Case 77 : Process507(xmlNodeList)
                Case 78 : Process507C(xmlNodeList)
                Case 79 : Process591(xmlDoc, marketMessage.MarketMessageID)
                Case 80 : Process594(xmlNodeList)
                Case 81 : Process595(xmlNodeList)
                Case 82 : Process596(xmlNodeList)
                Case 83 : Process597(xmlNodeList)
                Case 84 : Process598(xmlNodeList)
                Case 85 : Process601(xmlNodeList)
                Case 86 : Process602(xmlNodeList)
                Case 87 : Process700(xmlNodeList)
                Case 88 : Process700W(xmlNodeList)
                Case 89 : Process701(xmlNodeList)
                Case 90 : Process701W(xmlNodeList)

            End Select

            'Return RedirectToAction("Index")
        Next
        'Return RedirectToAction("Index")
        Return View()
    End If

    'Return View(marketmessage)
    Return View()
End Function
```

Comment: It's pretty difficult to determine the cause of any sort of performance issue without seeing any code. Now, maybe one way to avoid having to upload 2000 files via file uploads, might be to actually add support for uploading compressed files. Such as maybe one ZIP file with all of them. XML should compress very well which would make your actual data transfer much smaller.
More info on reading ZIP files: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404280%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I have updated the question to show my code, The code is working fine in that if i upload 1 via the controller action it does it in a matter of seconds so manually selecting the file I can do like at least 10-15 a minute but if i select 15 files it takes several minutes between 3-4 minutes, I have even tried iterating through files by putting them in server map path folder but the same speed issues occur, I am testing locally using sql express

Comment: Well, one simple way to determine where the overhead is, is by adding logging messages to the implementation, such as NLog or Log4Net, and seeing what is actually occurring during those minutes and how long each one takes. Debugging step by step could also give you clues.